# Python: проверить тип возврата функций

Tags: python

Есть следующий код. В главной функции определено еще две функции. Если обе вложенные функции возвращают True, то runcheckconn() должна вернуть True. Если одна из вложенных фнкций False, то runcheckconn() должна вернуть False

```
def runcheckconn():
    def checkDBfilesExists():
    ...................
    # возвращаем True
    def checkfdbconnection():
    ................... # предположим тут мы возвращаем False
    if all([checkDBfilesExists() and checkfdbconnection()]): # Если True и True то возвращаем True
        print "true main"
        return True
    else:
        print "false main"
        return False

runcheckconn()
```

Проблема начинается когда я пытаюсь получить результат из из MainApp.py

Я делаю так:

```
if checkconn.runcheckconn():
    print "ALL TRUE"
if not checkconn.runcheckconn():
    print "ALL FALSE"
```

В итоге если там был False, то тут упорно выводится True. В чем причина?

Comment: Эмъ... А вам зачем здесь `all`? Если можно просто `return checkDBfilesExists() and checkfdbconnection()`

И зачем вас второй раз вызывать функцию? Если можно просто:

    if checkconn.runcheckconn():
        print "ALL TRUE"
    else:
        print "ALL FALSE"

И почему `ALL FALSE`, ведь только один мог быть False, а другой True

Comment: По вопросу: т.е. получается, что checkDBfilesExists возвращает True, checkfdbconnection возвращает False, но при вызове

    if checkconn.runcheckconn():
        print "ALL TRUE"

у вас печатает True? Не совсем понял что у вас не получается

Comment: Получается, что
return checkDBfilesExists() and checkfdbconnection()
вернет или True или False ?

Только вопрос, почему указанный код делает вывод два раза?
Как сделать, чтобы был один?

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=7zxgKz9w

Comment: Давайте считать вместе )

1 вызов - в самом файле runcheckconn(). Зачем он вам, если вы его никак не используете?
2 вызов - вы же используете приведенный вами код?

    if checkconn.runcheckconn():
        print "ALL TRUE"
    if not checkconn.runcheckconn():
        print "ALL FALSE"

Тогда второй вызов будет выполняться при проверке условия `if checkconn.runcheckconn():`

3 вызов - будет выполняться уже при проверке условия `if not checkconn.runcheckconn():`

Чтобы такого избежать:

1 вызов обрамляем в

    if __name__ == '__main__'

А от третьего вызова избавляемся через `else`

Answer (score 1):

Вместо ифов, надо сделать простой return, это и по оптимизации получше и код понятней.

Надо просто написать `return checkDBfilesExists() and checkfdbconnection()`